# Same value is shown only one, how make it?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hallo I need to show same column value only one,but each other column value show to next row.
For Example, I have tables Person(iD, name, surname) and Contact(iD, description, contact), and one person has tree contacts.
How can I make this report ?

```
iD     Name     Surname    Description    Contact
5      Johny    Walker     Email          Johny.Walke@xzy.zz
                           Mobile         6546846168
                           Fax            688468
```

Comment: Display issues are not best handled in SQL...deal with this issue in whatever you are using to deliver the data to your clients (Excel for instance).  Other option is to pivot out the email vs mobile vs fax...you can return 3 columns (email, mobile, fax) instead of three rows if it's preferred.

Comment: But how can I delete them from output in OraWeb ?

Comment: Not sutre if I've ever heard of OraWeb

Comment: ohhh... found something (not in english): [www.oraweb.ca](http://www.oraweb.ca/) but it looks like it's just oracle?  dunno?

Comment: It looks like ORaWeb is the French BI offering from Oracle.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory something like the following construct should work in 8.1.6 or higher:

```
select
  case r when 1 then p.id end as id,
  case r when 1 then name end as name,
  case r when 1 then surname end as surname,
  description,
  contact
from
  person p, (
    select
      id,
      row_number() over (partition by id) as r,
      description,
      contact
    from
      contact
  ) c
where p.id = c.id;
```

but you should add ordering to the window function and an order by to the results to force the output to always be in the correct order.

Comment: What does mean add ordering to window function ? I add Order By but still is error displayed like this:

"missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification"
*Cause:    Either the ORDER BY expression is mandatory for this function, or
           there is an aggregation group without any ORDER by expression.

For row where is row_number function

Comment: THX this is CORRECT, 
`code`
  select
  case r when 1 then p.id end as id,
  case r when 1 then name end as name,
  case r when 1 then surname end as surname,
  description,
  contact
from
  person p, (
    select
      id,
      row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as r,
      description,
      contact
    from
      contact
  ) c
where p.id = c.id
order by name;